# ScrollView not allowing me to select from Component dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, components, scrollview

First of all let me share my code along with the current result of what I have going.

```
return(
    <DismissKeyBoard>
    <View>   
       <Formik
            initialValues ={{user: 'User ', place: '', description: '', comments: '',datePosted: new Date(), location: '', eventDate: ''}}
            onSubmit ={logInfo}>
            {props =>(
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.form}>    

                <Text  style={styles.text}>Pick a place for the event</Text>

                <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                         placeholder='Insert place to find'
                         minLength={2}
                         keyboardAppearance={'light'}
                         fetchDetails={false} 
                         onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                             {props.values.location= data.description}
                                 console.log("hello",props.values.location);
                                }}

                            styles={{
                            textInputContainer: {
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                borderTopWidth: 0,
                                borderBottomWidth:0,
                                width: '100%',
                                },
                             textInput: {
                                fontSize: 16
                                },
                             predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                                color: '#1faadb',
                                height:'100%',
                                },
                            }}

                            query={{
                                key: '',
                                language: 'en', // language of the results
                              }}

                        />


                   <View style={styles.container}>    
                    <Text
                        placeholder= {props.values.user}
                        onChangeText = {props.handleChange('user')}
                        values = {props.values.user} 
                        style={styles.text}>{props.values.user}</Text>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder= 'Place (e.g Honolulu)'
                        onChangeText = {props.handleChange('place')}
                        values = {props.values.place} 
                        style={styles.text}/>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder= 'Description (e.g This is located...)'
                        onChangeText = {props.handleChange('description')}
                        values = {props.values.description} 
                        style={styles.text}/>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder= 'Comment (e.g This is fun because...)'
                        onChangeText = {props.handleChange('comments')}
                        values = {props.values.comments} 
                        style={styles.text}/>
                    <Text  style={styles.text} >Pick a date for the event</Text>
                    <DatePicker
                        date={props.values.eventDate}
                        onDateChange={(date) => {props.values.eventDate= date}}
                        values = {props.values.eventDate} />
                    {/* <Text  style={styles.text}>Location</Text> */}

                    <View  style={styles.viewbtn}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.handleSubmit} style={styles.btn} ><Text style={styles.txtbtn} >Submit</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        {/* <Button title="Submit" onPress={props.handleSubmit}  /> */}
                    </View>

                    </View>    

            </View>
            </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>

            )}
        </Formik> 
    </View>      
    </DismissKeyBoard>           
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
       // flex:1,
        paddingTop:20,
      //  margin: 10,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    // form:{
    //     alignItems: 'flex-start',
    //     paddingTop:40,

    // },
    text:{
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderColor: 'black',
        paddingTop:15, 
    },
    viewbtn:{
        paddingTop:15,
    },
    btn:{
        backgroundColor: 'purple',
        padding:20,
        margin:20,
        width: 100,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius : 5,
    },
    txtbtn:{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 14,
        color: 'orange'
    },
})
```

[image]

**The issue**

When I click on the GooglePlacesAutoComplete I am able to see the list of places, but then when I click on any of the found places it will not take the input.

**Observations**

1. When the `<GooglePlacesAutocomplete />` is NOT inside a ScrollView I cannot see the suggestion.
2. When the `<GooglePlacesAutocomplete />` is NOT within any other `<View></View>` it works perfectly fine.

**Warning**

With the above code I also get this warning message *"VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead."*

**Desired Result**

I would like to have the `<GooglePlacesAutocomplete />`  component displayed on top of the form, without any weird errors and its functionalities working properly. (Preferably as shown in the picture)

**Edit**

I am importing `import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';` from https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete

I am not an expert in GUI, an explanation would be very appreciated and welcomed. If additional information is required I would be more than happy to provide it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I faced the same problem and the one thing that helped me solve the problem was adding
`keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` inside the `<ScrollView>` as a prop.

This is my code snippet.

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}> 
      <SelectionDD studentstatus={studentStatus}/>
      <SearchableDD collegeNames={collegeNames} placeholder='University'/>
</ScrollView>
```